# git heroku not download collaborators recent push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

A collaborator on a heroku app Im working on pushed some code, moments before I made a push, as the owner I rolled back the app, but now I can not seem to download the code to the my local repository?

I've tried rebasing the branch, fetching and reseting the HEAD, everything said it is up todate? I even deleted the whole local repository as a last resort and clones the app, is rolling it back in Heroku causing the problem?

When I do `heroku releases` I try to `git checkout <deploy of collaborator>` and I get a pathspec error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can`t you see his commit in reflog (git reflog)? if it is the case ask him to push again or push to a feature branch and cherry pick the commit you needed in to your branch

Comment: i could, but I couldn't check out his branch, ended up getting him to recommit the changes. Weirdest thing.